# Full calendar events disappearing when using multiple calendars - Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, calendar, fullcalendar

I’m want to use Fullcalendar in my Meteor application to show the schedule of multiple items on one page.  Each item has its own basic week calendar view and its own events.  I was able to get the calendar to work as expected when only rendering one calendar.

With multiple calendars, events show up on first render but disappear when refetching events.  I have a custom button which changes the weeks of every calendar simultaneously.  After changing weeks the events disappear.  The same functionality worked fine when using a single calendar.  I referenced George McKnight's video for a starting reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e2jRxw0saRc

I think it an issue with rendering multiple calendars within a for loop.  I've seen a few forums talking about the event 'stick' option but being I didn't have an issue with events disappearing with one calendar I don't think that's the issue. I also saw some talk pointing me towards trying event sources, but not sure how I'd apply it in my use case.

Here’s a snippet of my code:

```js
Template.ScheduleAdminTest.rendered = function () {
    var orgId = UserProfiles.findOne({userId:Meteor.userId()}).orgId;
    var items = Items.find({}, {reactive: false}).fetch();
    
    // INITIALIZE VARIABLES
    var itemId;
    var events;
    var itemReservations;

    // RENDER CALENDAR FOR EACH ITEM
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        itemId = items[i]._id;

        $('#calendar-'+itemId).fullCalendar({
            header:  false,
            firstDay: 0, // SUNDAY
            contentHeight: 100,
            eventLimit: true,
            defaultView: 'basicWeek',
            views: {
                week: {
                    eventLimit: 5
                }
            },
            editable: false,
            eventColor: '#2BA9A5',
            events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
                events = [];
                itemReservations = ItemReservation.find({itemId: itemId}, {reactive:false});
                
                itemReservations.forEach(function(reservation) {
                    events.push({
                        id: reservation._id,
                        title: reservation.title,
                        start: reservation.start,
                        end: reservation.end,
                        quoteId: reservation.quoteId,
                        itemId: reservation.itemId,
                    });
                });

                callback(events);
            },
            eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                // code for rendering a modal for editing and reviewing events
            },
            dayClick: function( date, jsEvent, view) {   
                // code to display modal for adding an event
            }

        });  // end calendar set

    } // end for loop for items
};
```

Comment: Where is vehicleId in $('#calendar-' +vehicleId) coming from? If it is undefined you are targeting multiple elements with the same id of 'calendar-', and possibly pushing your new updates to the first of them

Comment: Whoops!  Sorry I missed that edit when simplifying my code snippet.  It would be itemId in this example.  Nice catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this after each calendar has been rendered:

> ```
>   $('#calendar-'+itemId).fullCalendar('removeEvents');
>   $('#calendar-'+itemId).fullCalendar('addEventSource', events)
> ```

Comment: Well this is progress over where I was before.  The events are staying when I change weeks at least, but now when I click on events I'm getting: 'Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded'.  This might have something to do with my Event click function since when I comment it out the error goes away.  I'll investigate some more.

Comment: Also, I'm having troubles getting the calendar to reactively update when I make changes.  With a single calendar this code was working:  `Deps.autorun(function() {
    Items.find({}).fetch();
    $('.item-calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');  // common class for all calendars
});`

Comment: So the call stack error was occuring because all of the calendar events seem to be stored in some sub-properties of calEvents.  I ended up grabbing the fields I need before setting a Session variable that I was using in other calculations which fixed that issue.   Still having troubles with the .fullCalendar('refetch events') function with the 'addEventSource' method.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Got it!  Ended up removing events.option entirely and moving all of the logic into the Deps.autorun where I used the 'removeEvents' and 'addEventSource' functions you recommended.